# sending ether to external address using fallback function in an ethereum contract

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I am trying to create a contract, which when receives some ether, send them all to a fixed external account automatically. I need this for a website, where I have many customers depositing ether. I intend to provide each customer a unique ethereum account or contract account so that whenever they send some ether, my front end knows who has sent, and all of the funds I receive from all the customer goes to my fixed account "0x83fe472e50cf588f3fb309409bda2ab946248d8d".

my contract code is as follows:

```
contract Transfer_effiAnkit
{

    address constant private receiver = 0x83fe472e50cf588f3fb309409bda2ab946248d8d;


    function () payable 
    {
        receiver.send(msg.value);
    }

    function getAddress() returns(address){

        return receiver;
    }

}
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

your contract should works i recommend the use  of

```
mapping (address => uint256) balances;
```

to keep track of transactions

Comment: what if the same customer sends funds from two different accounts? I wanted to have one unique address for each customer so that I know which customer has sent what amount in total and internally the contract at that address is going to forward incoming funds to my primary address. hope I have clarified the requirement.

Comment: if you intend to provide each customer a unique contract address, the customer send ether to their unique contract which get forwarded to your wallet, the transactions on your wallet will show the ether coming from a contract address that way you can track each customer by their designated contract address